# Main Site Displaying subdirectory in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, subdirectory

My Main site displays (mypage.com/site) and all following pages include /site as well
How do I achieve (mypage.com) and no subdirectory displaying?

I have tried Removing the /site in the Site Address URL in Wordpress settings. 
But it broke my login and disables me from logging in.

what must I do to remove the /site subdirectory folder dislaying on my website?

What do I do in my htaccess file?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I believe you have to move the Wordpress core files - http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Also I believe you need to use a different htaccess for WP installs in subdirectories. http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: Thanks. I found out that the https plugin in my wordress was screwing me over. once disabled. Everything worked. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supposed that your WordPress installation is under /site folder. If it's true, you can do it:

If you already has changed the URL, on General panel, to http://mypage.com (without */site*), you just need to **copy** the `index.php` (under `site/`) to the root folder.

After copy the index.php file, edit it, adding `site/` to the path to `wp-blog-header.php`:

`require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/site/wp-blog-header.php' );`

The detailed steps of this process are on *"Using a pre-existing subdirectory install
"* at WordPress docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change your document root in Apache?

Something like:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/your/site
```

I don't know if you have access to your hosting, but this would be the best solution as far as I know.

If you can't do it for yourself, you can ask to your hosting provider to do it for you.